# Message: 'Creating converter from %s to %s'

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, h5py, onnx, onnxruntime

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/logging/__init__.py", line 442, in format
    return self._format(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/logging/__init__.py", line 437, in _format
    return self._fmt % values
KeyError: 'rank'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/logging/__init__.py", line 1102, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/logging/__init__.py", line 945, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/logging/__init__.py", line 683, in format
    s = self.formatMessage(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/logging/__init__.py", line 652, in formatMessage
    return self._style.format(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/logging/__init__.py", line 444, in format
    raise ValueError('Formatting field not found in record: %s' % e)
ValueError: Formatting field not found in record: 'rank'
Call stack:
  File "/home/pt/gnmt/train.py", line 638, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/pt/gnmt/train.py", line 540, in main
    trainer = trainers.Seq2SeqTrainer(**trainer_options)
  File "/home/pt/gnmt/seq2seq/train/trainer.py", line 133, in __init__
    self.optimizer = torch.optim.__dict__[opt_name](params, **opt_config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/optim/adam.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(params, defaults)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/optim/optimizer.py", line 266, in __init__
    self.add_param_group(cast(dict, param_group))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_compile.py", line 22, in inner
    import torch._dynamo
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_dynamo/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import allowed_functions, convert_frame, eval_frame, resume_execution
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1078, in _handle_fromlist
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_dynamo/allowed_functions.py", line 26, in <module>
    from . import config
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1078, in _handle_fromlist
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_dynamo/config.py", line 49, in <module>
    torch.onnx.is_in_onnx_export: False,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 1834, in __getattr__
    return importlib.import_module(f".{name}", __name__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 129, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/onnx/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from ._internal.onnxruntime import (
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/onnx/_internal/onnxruntime.py", line 35, in <module>
    import onnxruntime  # type: ignore[import]
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/onnxruntime/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from onnxruntime.capi._pybind_state import (
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/onnxruntime/capi/_pybind_state.py", line 13, in <module>
    from . import _ld_preload  # noqa: F401
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1078, in _handle_fromlist
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/onnxruntime/capi/_ld_preload.py", line 24, in <module>
    import onnxruntime.providers.tvm
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/onnxruntime/providers/tvm/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .ort import ANSOR_TYPE, AUTO_TVM_TYPE, onnx_compile
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/onnxruntime/providers/tvm/ort.py", line 14, in <module>
    from tvm import auto_scheduler, autotvm, relay
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1078, in _handle_fromlist
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tvm/relay/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    from . import frontend
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1078, in _handle_fromlist
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tvm/relay/frontend/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    from .transformer import bert_from_hdf5, get_conf_by_name, transformer_from_pt
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tvm/relay/frontend/transformer.py", line 31, in <module>
    import h5py
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    _register_converters()
Message: 'Creating converter from %s to %s'
Arguments: (5, 7)
```

reports an error when I am running a model, this error must have onnx, onnxruntime_gpu, tvm and h5py in your python package, the h5py is necessary for tensorflow，and onnx is necessary for tvm, if I pip3 uninstall the one of onnx, onnxruntime_gpu, tvm and h5py, this error is not occur，The version is as follows，onnx==1.15.0，onnxruntime-gpu==1.13.1，tvm==0.9.0，h5py==3.10.0